# Limit $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{10t^3+3t-18}{6-kt^3} = 2$

Tags: calculus

I am working on the limit problem:

$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{10t^3+3t-18}{6-kt^3} = 2$

so far I believe I have broken down the numerator correctly by doing:

$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{t^3(10+\dfrac{3}{t^2}-\dfrac{18}{t^3})}{6-kt^3} = 2$

However I am ending up with $0-0$ in the denominator which I know shouldn't be happening. How do I distribute the $t^3$ so that I don't end up with $t^3(\dfrac{6}{t^3}-\dfrac{k}{t^3})$ which gives me $0-0$ after the $t^3$ cancel each other out?

Comment: Once you factor out $t^3$ from the denominator, you are left with $t^3(\frac{6}{t^3} - k)$, not $t^3(\frac{6}{t^3} - \frac{k}{t^3})$

Comment: How about dividing numerator and denominator by $t^3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac {10t^3+3t-18}{6-kt^3} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac {10 \left( 1+\frac 3{10t^2}-\frac 9{5t^3}\right )}{-k \left( 1-\frac 6{t^3}\right )} = -\frac {10}k
$$
Now, just find $k$ from
$$
-\frac {10}k = 2 \implies k = -5
$$